# R: Non-greedy version of setdiff?

Tags: r

Here's `setdiff` normal behaviour:

```
x <- rep(letters[1:4], 2)
x
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d"

y <- letters[1:2]
y
# [1] "a" "b"

setdiff(x, y)
# [1] "c" "d"
```

… but what if I want `y` to be taken out *only once*, and therefore get the following result?

`# "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d"`

I'm guessing that there is an easy solution using either `setdiff` or `%in%`, but I just cannot see it.

Comment: I'm doing something a bit like that right now, but yes, it's kinda overkill. I'm hoping that there is a simpler solution out there, and that I am just missing the obvious.

Comment: In general and for next time, it's good if you include what you have tried ("_I'm doing something a bit like that right now_"). It demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, and it saves us from reiterating obvious answers. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for the feedback. I would have done as you recommend, but unfortunately, had nothing to put up here, having found only 'greedy' solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`match` returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second. It's used as an index constructor:

```
x[ -match(y,x) ]
 #[1] "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

If there are duplicates in 'y' and you want removal in proportion to their numbers therein, then the first thing that came to my mind is a for-loop:

```
y <- c("a","b","a")
x2 <- x
for( i in seq_along(y) ){ x2 <- x2[-match(y[i],x2)] }

> x2
[1] "c" "d" "b" "c" "d"
```

This would be one possible result of using the tabling approach suggested below. Uses some "set" functions, but this is not really a set problem. Seems somewhat more "vectorised":

```
c( table(x [x %in% intersect(x,y)]) - table(y[y %in% intersect(x,y)]) , 
   table( x[!x %in% intersect(x,y)]) )
a b c d 
0 1 2 2
```

Comment: That should work, although I'm amazed that there is no other way than to loop if there are duplicates in `y`.

Comment: Well, I think it's kind of an odd request. You offer no motivating use case. Without better description of the need for such a pre-made function to do this, your "amazement" seems a bit presumptuous.

Comment: Peace and love OP here. Here's the use case: (1) I have a vector of elements, and need to "subtract" another vector from it. (2) Both vectors are chatacter. (3) There might be duplicates in both vectors. --- It might be that this is not a very frequent use case, but it's really a subtraction/removal operation.

Comment: If yu wanted additional strategy ideas, then consider "subtracting" a tabled version of `y` from a tabled version of `x` for the intersection of their names.

Comment: Saw your edit, thanks a lot: I am probably going to end up using something like that.

Answer (score 1):

`vecsets` package has `vsetdiff` function for this.

```
x <- rep(letters[1:4], 2)
y <- letters[1:2]

vecsets::vsetdiff(x, y)
#[1] "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another looping method. I think 42's method is cleaner, but it provides another option.

```
# construct a table containing counts for all possible values in x and y in y
myCounts <- table(factor(y, levels=sort(union(x, y))))

# extract these elements from x
x[-unlist(lapply(names(myCounts),
                 function(i) which(i == x)[seq_len(myCounts[i])]))]
```

The "non-greedy" aspect comes from `[seq_len(myCounts[i])]` which only takes the number of identical elements that are present in y